# Regular expression to extract pattern form python pandas dataframe column with parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, pandas, parentheses

I have this specific string  :   Oxidation mark (2-3,20mm- 110mm)  , in dataframe column .
The text between parenthesis can be anything .

I tried to extract this by the below code:

```
str.extract('(Oxidation mark )[\(][.]*[\)]')
```

But its giving `NaN` .

Comment: does the column only contain the above format? Can there be any text after the closing bracket?

Comment: `r'\b(Oxidation mark\s*\(.*\))'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\b(Oxidation\s+mark\s*\([^()]*\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PFGr9U/1/).

*Details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(Oxidation\s+mark\s*\([^()]*\))` - Group 1:

  - `Oxidation` - a word
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `mark` - another word
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
  - `\([^()]*\)` - `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char.